# XmlPullParserException during parsing XML with XMLPullParser

Tags: java, android

Need your help to resolve this :
Trying to parse this xml -

```
<LungProtocol><configuration name="FLUS Sitting">   
    <segment order="1" name="left upper anterior">
    <segment order="2" name="left lower anterior">  
</configuration>
<configuration name="FLUS Supine">  
    <segment order="1" name="left upper anterior">
    <segment order="2" name="left lower anterior">
</configuration></LungProtocol>
```

With following function -

```
public List<LungSegment> parse(InputStream is, String configuration) {  
       try {  
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);  
        XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();  
        segment = new LungSegment();
        parser.setInput(is, null);  
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "configuration");
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {  
            String tagname = parser.getName();  
            switch (eventType) {  
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:  
                if(("configuration").equalsIgnoreCase(tagname) && parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase(configuration)){
                    eventType = parser.next();
                    //eventType = parser.next();
                    tagname = parser.getName();
                    Log.v("XMLTAG", "configuration = "+configuration);
                if (("segment").equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)) {  
                    // create a new instance of segment  
                      segment = new LungSegment();
                      segment.setSegmentName(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                      segment.setSegmentOrder(Integer.parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "order")));
                } 
                }
                break;  

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:  
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("segment")) {  
                    // add segment object to list  
                    segments.add(segment);  
                } else if (("configuration").equalsIgnoreCase(tagname) && parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase(configuration)) {
                        return segments;
                }  
                break;   
            }  
            eventType = parser.next();  
        }  

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  

    return segments;  
}
```

where configuration is the name attribute of configuration tag. But getting an exception -

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}configuration (position:START_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42323800)
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an end tag for "<LungProtocol>"  (like "</LungProtocol>") at the end of the xml document?

Comment: Yes, edited the question. I am using end tag.

Comment: Not sure if this is the fix. But it sounds logical to replace this line: parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "configuration"); with this: parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "LungProtocol");

Comment: Could you paste the whole stack trace? Or at least the place where it is throwing this exception.

Comment: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}configuration (position:START_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@42323800) 
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056)
at controller.XmlPullParserHandler.parse(XmlPullParserHandler.java:35)
at activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

Answer (score 0):

Make these two changes in your code:

1. Make xml valid. The segment tags are not ended. They should be:`<segment order="1" name="left upper anterior"/>`
2. Remove the line `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "configuration");`

Everything else looks fine. I was able to run your code as well.